# Static analysis of Scala locking / synchronization code using JCIP / JSR-305 annotations

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, findbugs, jsr305

Is there any way for me to statically analyze Scala code for locking / synchronization issues using the [JCIP](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) or [JSR-305](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/) annotations (e.g. @GuardedBy).

Both FindBugs and IntelliJ IDEA have excellent support for these annotations when checking Java code, but I haven't had much luck getting them to work with Scala code.  When I've tried applying these annotations in my Scala code, the code compiles fine but both tools fail to flag violations in intentionally-buggy programs.

I know that FindBugs analyzes JVM bytecode, so perhaps the annotations aren't compiling to the expected output when applied in Scala.

Comment: Looks @GuardedBy JCIP annotation is mostly for documentation purpose as per http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/feature-requests/119/